# Google+ кросспостинг

Tags: php, javascript, google-api, google-plus

Есть ли способ автоматически постить в Google+ только при помощи API, без применения сторонних костылей? Если есть плагины к различным движкам, то с удовольствием поковыряю.

**P.S.** Загугливание не дало результатов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Note: The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public data. All API calls require either an OAuth 2.0 token or an API key.
```

С главной страницы [Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/).

Comment: Ужас, как такое не заметил, пора отдыхать. Спасибо)